# Which is the best way to retrieve json content?

Tags: swift

When asking to retrieve a data/content in swift i found two ways of doing it:

- 1

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      if let url = NSURL(string: "https://freegeoip.net/json/") {
          do {
              let contents = try NSString(contentsOfURL: url, usedEncoding: nil)
              print(contents)
          }catch{
              print("Error accessing content!")
          }
      } else{
          print("Bad URL!")
      }
  }
  ```
- 2

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      let url = NSURL(string: "https://freegeoip.net/json/")

      let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data, response, error) in
          if let content = data{
              do {
                  let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(content, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
                  print(jsonResult)
              } catch{
                  print("JSON serialization failed")
              }
          }
      }

      task.resume()
  }
  ```

Which one is technically the correct/best way and why?

Answer (score 2):

- Way 2, Because `Foundation` provide `NSJSONSerialization` to work with JSON.
- In first way, your content may be doesn't have NSArray or NSDictionary type.
- In second way, you can use Asynchronous NSULRSession for the best.

Answer (score 1):

In any case way 2.

**Never** use way 1 to retrieve data from over the Internet. Due to the synchronous behavior it will block the current thread and in the worst case your whole application.

The `contentsOfURL` API of String, Data, Array, Dictionary, Image etc. is supposed to be used **only** with URLs in the local file system.

Comment: Thanks, vadian. You mean basically that the first one is just for using with raw data, right!?

Comment: No, the kind of data doesn't matter. It's a question about local (disk) vs. remote (network) resources.

Answer (score 0):

It's depends on your json data. If your json data contains only single line or single object you can use 1st one. Because it store your data as a string. On other hand if your json data contains lots of data like array in array , array in dictionary , dictionary in array for this you have to use second one because you have to process further to get child of your array or dictionary.